# Select2 performance Issue

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, angularjs-select2

I am using AngularJS and [`Select2`](https://select2.org/) to display 80000 data in single select dropdown , but its taking lot of time around 2 min to display. How can I improve the performance of [`Select2`](https://select2.org/)?

Comment: Even if you will not use `select2` but will use a regular `select` html element - you will still have not a great performance and user experience. 80k options, do you really think user will want to scroll/search through all of them? Loading that much data into the DOM is always going to be slow, so I think in your case it would be better to use autocomplete function of `select2` to allow users to search for only the entries they need.

Comment: You should consider **uib-typeahead** instead of select2 dropdown